# Conditional groupby sum

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would like to create a column that contains the sum of all amounts that occurred in a given hour. For example, if the row I am looking at has 0 under the column 0, I would like the volume column for that row to be the total volume for all amounts that occurred within that hour.

So:

```
dat.groupby('Hours')['Amount'].sum()
```

by performing groupby hours and summing the amount, I get the total amount of transactions that where made in each hour.

```
Hours
0     257101.87
1     146105.69
2     108819.17
....
45    532181.83
46    448887.69
47    336343.60
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

Problem is my database contains 1000s of rows and I can't simply create a new column with the values from the groupby, I would need a condition stipulating that if the value on the hour column is 0 then return the sum of all the amounts where the hour is 0.

So the desired result would be something like this

```
Hours      Amount      Total
 0           20         100
 0           20         100
 0           60         100
 1           10          20
 1           10          20
 2           50          50
```

In this scenario I would want to create the total column and return the sum of all amounts that occurred in a given hour

Answer (score 2):

Groupby + transform should do it

```
df["Total"] = df.groupby("Hours")["Amount"].transform(sum)
```

---

Why this works...

A [transform in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) is like a split-apply-combine-merge in one go. You keep the same axis length after the groupby reduction.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the output of `dat.groupby('Hours')['Amount'].sum()`, and `merge` it with the original set on the `Hours` column:

```
totals = dat.groupby('Hours')['Amount'].sum()

dat_with_totals = dat.merge(totals, on='Hours')
```

Comment: Please elaborate.